# How can I disable mouse events in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having troubles with disabling mouse events after the computer reads one of them. I'm using Turtle. My code:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()

#Box -------------------------- (Apple)

b1 = turtle.Turtle()
b1.color("red")
b1.ht()
b1.speed(0)
b1.penup()
b1.goto(-520, -200)
b1.begin_fill()
b1.forward(240)
b1.right(90)
b1.forward(100)
b1.right(90)
b1.forward(240)
b1.right(90)
b1.forward(100)
b1.right(90)
b1.penup()
b1.end_fill()

#Box2 --------------------------- (Banana)

b2 = turtle.Turtle()
b2.color("yellow")
b2.ht()
b2.speed(0)
b2.penup()
b2.goto(-120, -200)
b2.begin_fill()
b2.forward(240)
b2.right(90)
b2.forward(100)
b2.right(90)
b2.forward(240)
b2.right(90)
b2.forward(100)
b2.right(90)
b2.penup()
b2.end_fill()

#Box3 --------------------------- (Orange)

b3 = turtle.Turtle()
b3.color("orange")
b3.ht()
b3.speed(0)
b3.penup()
b3.goto(280, -200)
b3.begin_fill()
b3.forward(240)
b3.right(90)
b3.forward(100)
b3.right(90)
b3.forward(240)
b3.right(90)
b3.forward(100)
b3.right(90)
b3.penup()
b3.end_fill()

def pos(x,y):
    print(x,y)

    if x >= -520 and x <= -280 and y >= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("apple")
        return
    if x >= -120 and x <= 120 and y>= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("banana")
        return
    if x >= 280 and x <= 520 and y>= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("orange")
        return


while True:
    wn.onscreenclick(pos)
    wn.update()
```

What do I want: After clicking a box, it will read the mouse event and print the corresponding fruit, but only for the first time; when clicking a box again, it won't print the fruit. That means clicking `Box2`, `Box3` or `Box1` again won't print the corresponding fruit anymore when `Box1`, for example, is clicked. But it's not working, even with the `return` statement. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No global boolean needed, you can simply turn off the button event handler once you've hit on a colored square:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def pos(x, y):
    print(x, y)

    if -520 <= x <= -280 and -300 <= y <= -200:
        screen.onscreenclick(None)
        print("apple")
    elif -120 <= x <= 120 and -300 <= y <= -200:
        screen.onscreenclick(None)
        print("banana")
    elif 280 <= x <= 520 and -300 <= y <= -200:
        screen.onscreenclick(None)
        print("orange")

screen = Screen()

# Box -------------------------- (Apple)

b1 = Turtle()
b1.ht()
b1.color("red")
b1.speed('fastest')
b1.penup()
b1.goto(-520, -200)
b1.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    b1.forward(240)
    b1.right(90)
    b1.forward(100)
    b1.right(90)
b1.end_fill()

# Box2 --------------------------- (Banana)

b2 = Turtle()
b2.ht()
b2.color("yellow")
b2.speed('fastest')
b2.penup()
b2.goto(-120, -200)
b2.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    b2.forward(240)
    b2.right(90)
    b2.forward(100)
    b2.right(90)
b2.end_fill()

# Box3 --------------------------- (Orange)

b3 = Turtle()
b3.ht()
b3.color("orange")
b3.speed('fastest')
b3.penup()
b3.goto(280, -200)
b3.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    b3.forward(240)
    b3.right(90)
    b3.forward(100)
    b3.right(90)
b3.end_fill()

screen.onscreenclick(pos)
screen.mainloop()
```

The way I would go about this problem is not click on the screen and calculate which rectangle we're over, but rather make the rectangles out of turtles, and let the individual turtle `onclick()` methods do the work:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from functools import partial

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 240, 100
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def click(fruit, x, y):
    print(x, y)
    print(fruit)

    apple.onclick(None)
    banana.onclick(None)
    orange.onclick(None)

screen = Screen()
offset = screen.window_width()/2 - WIDTH/2

# Box -------------------------- (Apple)

apple = Turtle()
apple.color("red")
apple.shape("square")
apple.shapesize(HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE)
apple.penup()
apple.goto(-offset, -150)
apple.onclick(partial(click, "apple"))

# Box2 --------------------------- (Banana)

banana = apple.clone()
banana.color("yellow")
banana.setx(0)
banana.onclick(partial(click, "banana"))

# Box3 --------------------------- (Orange)

orange = banana.clone()
orange.color("orange")
orange.setx(offset)
orange.onclick(partial(click, "orange"))

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global boolean variable

```
clicked = False

def pos(x,y):
    global clicked
    
    if clicked: return
    clicked = True
    
    print(x,y)

    if x >= -520 and x <= -280 and y >= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("apple")
        return
    if x >= -120 and x <= 120 and y>= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("banana")
        return
    if x >= 280 and x <= 520 and y>= -300 and y <= -200:
        print("orange")
        return
```